# Keeping the value of a String passed into a BigDecimal exactly the same

Tags: java, format, double, bigdecimal

I have a `String` in an array that looks exactly like this: `-000000000000256.07`.

I want to pass it into a `BigDecimal` variable to look exactly like it goes above; 17 digits and 2 decimal points. I've tried to do it by:

`BigDecimal bd = BigDecimal.valueOf(Double.parseDouble(splitRow[6])).setScale(17, 2);`

which gives me the result: `-256.07000000000000000` stored in the variable.

How do I get the format I require?

Comment: AFAIK you can't store it in a `BigDecimal` with this format, all the leading `0` will be ignored and removed.

Comment: Do you understand what `setScale` does?

Comment: What is the goal?

Comment: I'm taking it from a CSV, performing calculations on the number, then writing it to a new CSV where it has to match that format.

Comment: Separate the calculation from how it's represented in the new CSV.

Comment: By "perform calculations" what precision and accuracy do you need?  Is `double` the correct semantics?  Are you just trying to use BigDecimal to format the result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Java [**BigDecimal**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html) holds only the numeric value, so it won't be possible to store the number `-000000000000256.07` in a `BigDecimal`, all the leading zeros will be ommitted.

You can instead store it as `-256.07` in a `BigDecimal` then format it again (when you need to display it), using [**DecimalFormat**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html).

A sample code would look like:

```
new DecimalFormat("000000000000000.##")
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `BigDecimal` stores the actual numerical value.

When printing it, it will trim the leading `0`s (but maintain the sign and trailing `0`s), see [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#toString%28%29).

What you can do is format the `BigDecimal`'s `String` representation according to your expectations.

For instance:

```
String s = "-000000000000256.07";
BigDecimal bd = new BigDecimal(s);

//                 |start of format
//                 ||keep sign
//                 |||leading 0s
//                 ||||width
//                 |||| |decimal width
//                 |||| |   |newline
//                 |||| |   | 
System.out.printf("%+019.2f%n", bd.doubleValue());
```

**Output**

```
-000000000000256.07
```

**Note**

- The specified format works with the specific width.
- A numerical `String` with different width will obviously print different if using this format.
- If you want a robust solution to keep the exact `String` representation, use the `String` and only use `BigDecimal` when you need to perform actual calculations.